# Grant permission to queues to another schema in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-aq

Hi I have a oracle queue in one schema namely aqs

**sample queue**

```
   BEGIN DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE(
     Queue_name          => 'AQS.MOb_MSG',
     Queue_table         => 'AQS.MOb_QT',
     Queue_type          =>  0,
     Max_retries         =>  5,
     Retry_delay         =>  0,
     dependency_tracking =>  FALSE,
     comment             => 'SAMPLE');
  END;
```

I have the corresponding Queue table created.It works fine.

Now i do want to provide the select grant for the queue using another schema named "mob".How do i provide grant to another schema for a queue?Do i need to provide the select access for the queue or queue table.

I tried using grant select on AQS.MOb_MSG to mob , it is not working! saying object does not exists.

Answer (score 4):

```
EXECUTE DBMS_AQADM.grant_queue_privilege ( 
   privilege     =>     'ALL', or (enqueue) or (dequeue)
   queue_name    =>     'AQS.MOb_MSG', 
   grantee       =>     'grantee_user', 
   grant_option  =>      FALSE/TRUE);
```

If you want grant direct access to queue table. You have to  do this.`grant select on MOb_QT to xxxx`

Comment: I tried this, but it just won't work? Are other permissions necessary?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_aqadm.htm#ARPLS65303 , Security Model